# Whats wrong with this click event?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm just fooling around on meteor, trying to figure out what I did wrong here with this code. Does it have something to do with meteor being different or is my jQuery just off? And I think it's obvious what I want to happen here but if you don't understand I'd like this to alert("dont touch that") on the button click.

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
     alert("dont touch that");
   });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>bubblePop</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Clic" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Template.hello.events({
  "click [type='button']": function (evt, template) {
    alert("don't touch that");
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 This one is better than using JQuery because if there is more than one template it will still work. It also solves the op's problem because the template is rendered after `document.ready` fires

Answer (score 1):

Since you are generating the elements using a template it is dynamic, so use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', "input[type="button"]", function () {
    alert("dont touch that");
});
```

Comment: As an alternative: `$("button").on('click', function() {alert("dont touch that");});`.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors in jQuery are css-ish. When it is just a string it looks for elements of that type. So passing "button" makes it look for button elements (of which there are none) and as a result no handler is attached.

You probably wanted to target your input element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input").click(function(){
  alert("dont touch that");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$('input')`, or `$('input[type="button"]')`, or give your button an ID and reference that in your jQuery selector aka `$('#ButtonID')`